# java reading numbers, interpreting as octal, want interpreted as string

Tags: java, yaml

i am having an issue, where java is reading an array list from a YAML file of numbers, or strings, and it is interpreting the numbers as octal if it has a leading 0, and no 8-9 digit.

is there a way to force java to read the yaml field as a string?

code:

```
ArrayList recordrarray = (ArrayList) sect.get("recordnum");
   if (recordrarray != null) {
      recno = join (recordrarray, " ");
   }
```

HAVE ALSO TRIED:

```
Iterator<String> iter = recordrarray.iterator();
       if (iter.hasNext()) recno = " " +String.valueOf(iter.next());
       System.out.println(" this recnum:" + recno);
       while (iter.hasNext()){
          recno += ""+String.valueOf(iter.next()));

        System.out.println(" done recnum:" + String.valueOf(iter.next()));

       }
```

the input is such:
061456 changes to 25390
061506 changes to 25414
061559 -> FINE

it took a while to figure out what it was doing, and apparently this is a common issue for java,

ideas?
thanks

edit: using jvyaml

yaml:

```
  22:
country_code: ' '
description: ''
insection: 1
recordnum:
  - 061264
type: misc
```

yaml loading:

```
import org.jvyaml.YAML;
Map structure = new HashMap();
structure = (Map) YAML.load(new FileReader(structurefn)); // load the structure file
```

Comment: The code you're showing does not parse Strings into integers and is therefore not the code where your problem lies.

Comment: the data is not read any where else, aside from being loaded from the yaml and mapped to the "sect" hash.  can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: "061456 changes to 25390" -- where's the code where this happens?

Comment: where i posted above, i can not find where it is making this translation, but the output of the print statements above indicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you reading the file? The problem lies in where the file contents are being read. Most likeley the `recordarray` list contains integers, ie. they have alreadey been parsed. Find the place where the records are being read. Maybe you are doing something like this:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(record);
```

Use this instead:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(record, 10);
```

Comment: It may be a big hash eventually, but something has to read the file and make that hash. Are you using a parsing library to read in the file? I'm guessing that's where your problem lies; perhaps one of your method calls has an incorrect parameter.

Comment: ok, the yaml file is a big hash, so to get this particular section out of it:
`
    Map sect = (Map) sections.get(s);
`

then to get the array out of that section:
  `  ArrayList recordrarray = (ArrayList) sect.get("recordnum");
   `
those are the only places its being read.

Comment: structure = (Map) YAML.load(new FileReader(structurefn)); // load the structure file  is all that is happening

Comment: @recursive9: can you attach the relevant portion of the YAML file? It may be the case that the YAML already contains the "wrong" numbers.

Comment: '  22:
    country_code: ' '
    description: ''
    insection: 1
    recordnum:
      - 061264
    type: misc'

Comment: If you haven't already dug through the API, do that. If nothing comes of it, I would download the source and step through that method call (assuming the parser is open source, of course).